# SVN external tagged at Last Changed Rev 'doesn't exist' according to server

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-externals

I am requesting from the SVN server a revision of an external which is guaranteed to exist, because it's the latest modified revision number. Instead of getting the external like normal, I get nondescript errors.

Here's my svn:externals definition for a particular external which I NEED to get at the listed `@revision_number`:

```
/repository/things/myexternal/tags/0.1@18152 myexternalfoldername
```

I have also tried changing the format of this information, like so:

```
-r18152 /repository/things/myexternal/tags/0.1 myexternalfoldername
```

I run `svn up` to pull externals in, but I get errors:

`svn: warning: W200000: Error handling externals definition for 'myexternal':
svn: warning: W170000: URL 'svn://svnserver/repository/things/myexternal/tags/0.1' at revision 18152 doesn't exist`

I have another external specified in a very similar way, but the error message is slightly different looking, though seemingly related:

`svn: warning: W160013: File not found: revision 97143, path 'repository/things/myexternal/tags/0.1'`

Running **svn info** on any of these external paths gives this:

`Path: myexternal
Working Copy Root Path: (my local copy path)
URL: /repository/things/myexternal/tags/0.1
Relative URL: ^/things/myexternal/tags/0.1
Repository Root: svn://svnserver/repository
Repository UUID: (uuid here)
Revision: 97143
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: somedude
Last Changed Rev: 18152
Last Changed Date: 2012-04-02 09:55:11 -0700 (Mon, 02 Apr 2012)`

Note the Last Changed Rev field. It's the revision I am requesting, and it is valid. It even has log entries if i query them.

Can anyone tell what could be wrong with this svn server request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through looking at logs at the tags/ folder level per Ben's answer, I have discovered that my externals are indeed not exactly valid at the listed 'Last Changed Rev' - but the reason is because another user moved the entire folder structure at one point to a different location buried within the repository (effectively modifying a tag after the fact, but it didn't change the svn info). Mayhem!

The 'Last Changed Rev' from `svn info` becomes unreliable in this case, because no files were modified, but the folder was moved to another location (and the commit messages within the tag didn't give any clues). So you end up with a tag in the known 'moved' location which you can fetch without specifying the revision you want at 'Last Changed Rev' -- but when you try to check out at a revision in which this tag external existed in a different level of the folder structure, you get these errors.

If I checkout at my tag revision and reference the old file location, it resolves the external!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a canonical source for some reason, but I *think* that "Last Changed Rev" for a directory refers to the last revision where any *file within the directory* was changed.

So you are probably in a situation where some file changed in rev 18152, and sometime *after* that the 1.0 tag was created. Thus at revision 18152, there really is no path as specified.

Take a look at `svn log -v` instead of `svn info` and you can probably see when the directory was created or copied from another directory. If not, then do the log on the parent instead. Repeat until you see where the directory was created.

Then, use *that* revision instead of the less useful "Last Changed Rev" from `svn info`.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I need to do some testing tomorrow, but I think this is the answer! :)